# Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Tags: java

Here is my code that has been giving the problems.

```
package ca.rhinoza.game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public boolean running = false;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";

    private JFrame frame;

    public Game(){
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

        frame = new JFrame(NAME);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){

        new Thread(this).start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop(){

    }

    public void run() {


    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Game().start();
    }


}
```

I have no idea why it is doing this.

**Edit:** 
I edited as per your request to see more code.

Comment: sounds like a local variable has applied the access specifier

Comment: For future reference, you should post the *exact* error message and indicate which line in your code causes it.

Comment: Eclipse was pointing out the same issue with my code. Turns out I have `swtich` instead of `switch`. Glad I wasted only few minutes on my error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are declaring a field outside of the class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public boolean running = false; /// <=============== invalid location 


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable { // <==== class starts here
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";
    ...
```

It must be placed inside a class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable { // <==== class starts here

    public boolean running = false; /// <=============== valid location

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that. Everyone makes mistakes. It is 1 am in the morning here. Have some patience and sympathy. No need to downvote the question..

Thanks to all those that kindly helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You put

```
public boolean running = false;
```

outside of a class definition, effectively in the global namespace. But there are no globals in Java. This is not legal.

I'll say, that's a *strange* error message for that though. I would expect a little more from the compiler. Something to the effect of `class` or `interface` or `enum` because once you start the statement with `public` there are exactly three legal things that can follow. But, it is what it is. So, the compiler is *right* to complain, I just would have expected a more informative error message.