# expecting EOF, found '<something>'

Tags: compiler-errors, processing, internal-compiler-error

My 1st post here so I'll try to keep it simple. I'm trying to create a plot of some mass spectrometry data using Processing. I wanted to write a sketch to parse data from pseudo-XML into tables and then to plot this data as points on 2 axes (time, mz) with the third axis, the signal, as the colour of the point.

At this stage I want the plot to be the dimensions of the data. In my test data this is 38 time points on the x axis, 51 mz points on the Y and signal ranging from 0 to 12,000. The bounds of a real data set will be a hundred times bigger in every dimension.

My issue is that the width and height of the plot is dependent on the data and establishing these limits involves a bit of code. In Processing you can only call *size()* immediately after *void setup()* so I put all the calculation code first. This threw the title error. I couldn't work around it so I output the data to three csv files and started on a 2nd sketch to import that data and plot it. I've run into the same error.

The exact error is *expecting EOF, found ''*, where  can be the first word on a line. It has been *for*, *mzTable* and *if*, depending on the code I've tried.

Here's the second sketch in full:

```
import java.io.*;

int debug = 1;

String target = "M1A crop.txt";  // test data


File file = new File(target);

// ~  ~  ~  

String folderPath = file.getParent(); // target folder path
String name = file.getName(); 

String mzData = folderPath + "\\" + name + " - mz data.csv" ;    // CSV file to open
String signalData = folderPath + "\\" + name + " - signal data.csv" ;    // CSV file to open
String summaryData = folderPath + "\\" + name + " - summary data.csv" ;    // CSV file to open

Table mzTable = new Table();
Table signalTable = new Table();
Table summaryTable = new Table();

mzTable = loadTable(mzData, "header");
signalTable = loadTable(signalData, "header");
summaryTable = loadTable(summaryData, "header");

int timeMin = summaryTable.getInt(0, "timeMin");
int timeMax = summaryTable.getInt(0, "timeMax");
int mzMin = summaryTable.getInt(0, "mzMin");
int mzMax = summaryTable.getInt(0, "mzMax");
int signalMin = summaryTable.getInt(0, "signalMin");
int signalMax = summaryTable.getInt(0, "signalMax");

width = mzTable.getColumnCount();  // this is the number of time points on the X axis
height = mzMax - mzMin;  // this is the number of mz points on the Y axis

println("time Min: " + timeMin + ", Max: " + timeMax);
println("mz Min: " + mzMin + ", Max: " + mzMax);
println("signal Min: " + signalMin + ", Max: " + signalMax);


void setup() {
  size(width, height);

}    // end of void setup()


void draw() {
  for(int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
      stroke(map(signalTable.getInt(x, y), signalMin, signalMax, 0, 255));
      point(x, y);
    }
  }  
}
```

The source of the error is identified as coming from line 19:

```
mzTable = loadTable(mzData, "header");
```

I'm no hacker but I can see there's nothing wrong with that code. If I comment out everything from *void setup()* onwards the code runs so its something to do with having the import and summary code outside of that function. If I put bad code in front of it, such as just *for(* then I get expecting EOF, found 'for'. Can anyone tell me why?

Many thanks in advance,

Chris

edited for derp 20:20 1-5-15

edit 22:00 1-5-15
I've just tried the sketch in Processing 3.0a7, which has much better error reporting. It has identified a different error with line 19: *Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens*. Searching for this error lead me to this questions with suggestions of a diagnosis. 
[Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537185/syntax-error-on-tokens-delete-these-tokens)

Comment: Looks like your XML is not valid. Have you checked it?

Comment: Its no longer XML. I'm importing ints from csv files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you should have at the top of your sketch are **declarations**. You can't have random code like reassignment and calls to the `println()` function up there. Code like that needs to be inside of a function.

For example, this line is fine because it's a declaration:

```
Table mzTable = new Table();
```

But this line is a no-go, because it's not a declaration:

```
mzTable = loadTable(mzData, "header");
```

To fix that error, you can combine them into one single declaration line:

```
Table mzTable = loadTable(mzData, "header");
```

Similarly, you can't have calls like this outside of a function, since it's not a declaration:

```
println("time Min: " + timeMin + ", Max: " + timeMax);
```

Get rid of those `println()` functions, or move them into the setup() function.

Same with these lines:

```
width = mzTable.getColumnCount();  // this is the number of time points on the X axis
height = mzMax - mzMin;  // this is the number of mz points on the Y axis
```

Those aren't declarations, so they have to be inside a function. Maybe try something like this:

```
void setup() {
  width = mzTable.getColumnCount();  // this is the number of time points on the X axis
  height = mzMax - mzMin;  // this is the number of mz points on the Y axis
  size(width, height);
}
```

Although, using the width and height variables like that seems like a bad idea, so instead you might do this:

```
void setup() {
  size(mzTable.getColumnCount(), mzMax - mzMin);
}
```

Processing will then set the width and height variables for you.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that works beautifully! I won't make that mistake again.